# phantomjs page.evaluate not returning expected value in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, phantomjs

The below prints to the screen { b: [ 'test' ] }. There are no values in the 'a' array printed.

Why would 'a' not have any items added to it while 'b' does? When it prints the outerhtml of each item in b, i can see they have the 'href' attribute.

```
phantom.create(function(ph) {
  return ph.createPage(function(page) {
    return page.open(url, function(status) {
      console.log("opened " + url + "? ", status);

      if (status === "fail") {
        ph.exit();
        return;
      }

      page.injectJs('jquery.min.js', function() {
        console.log("loaded jquery");

        setTimeout(function() {
          return page.evaluate(function() {

            var a = [],
              b = [];

            $("a").each(function() {
              a.push($(this).attr("href"));
              b.push($(this)[0].outerHTML);
            });

            return {
              a: a,
              b: b
            };

          }, function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            ph.exit();
          });
        }, 3000);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You're going to need to provide more context.

Comment: Your usage of the PhantomJS APIs is not what I'm expecting. What version are you using? For example: In my version (1.9.1), there is no `phantom.create()` method. Similarly, in my version, `injectJs` doesn't take a callback argument, it returns a boolean.

Comment: I am using the nodejs bridge to phantomjs which I think is why the methods are all async.  The bridge I am using is at https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node

Comment: Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference-WebPage#webpage-onConsoleMessage) and [`onError`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference-WebPage#onerror) events. Maybe there are errors. Do the `href` attributes exist?

Comment: when I use 'a.push('' + $(this).attr("href"));', it prints each href attribute.  Not sure why prepending an empty string to $(this).attr('href') works?